# Symfony access form-data in differen Route

Tags: symfony

I've got an symfony form which is rendered in Route X.
After sending, this controller also handles the first actions.
Later, this data should be accessed again in a different route, as I need it for an API endpoint in the controller.
In the symfony profiler I can still view the data under 'submitted data', but how do I access it?

Comment: Are you saving the submitted data to a database?

Comment: No I don‘t. Otherwise it would be easy….

Comment: Then you can save your data in the session and retrieve it.

Comment: It looks like what you need here is to persist your data somewhere. If it's a temporal data, you can use any cache mechanism for that. Otherwise, use your database.

Comment: I have stored it in the Session for now. Works for me I guess